# Selecionar Listas Específicas

Tags: c#, jquery, sharepoint

Tenho o seguinte código para retornar as bibliotecas do meu projeto em SharePoint:

```
function retornarLista() {
    collList = website.get_lists();

    context.load(collList);//, 'Include(TemplateType==109)'
    context.executeQueryAsync(onQuerySucceeded, onQueryFailed);
}

function onQuerySucceeded() {
    var listInfo = '';
    var listEnumerator = collList.getEnumerator();

    while (listEnumerator.moveNext()) {
        var oList = listEnumerator.get_current();
        listInfo += 'Title: ' + oList.get_title() +
            ' ID: ' + oList.get_id().toString() + '\n';
        $("#biblioteca").append("<option value='" + oList.get_id().toString() + "'>" + oList.get_title() + "</option>");
    }
}

function onQueryFailed() {
    alert("Failed");
}
```

Gostaria de retornar apenas as Bibliotecas de imagens para transferir para um `dropdown` de `select`, porém não tenho conseguido, alguém pode ajudar ?

Comment: Você tá usando SharePoint 2010 ou 2013?

Comment: Estou usando o 2013

Comment: Você pode verificar o templateID da lista pra ver se ela é uma biblioteca. Não conheço bibliotecas específicas apenas de imagens - se for um tipo de conteúdo (content type), você pode verificar se cada lista retornada possui esse tipo, e filtrar por isso.

Comment: Então, na interface de usuário que estou fazendo, ele precisa escolher se vai usar uma lista existente ou criar uma nova, e para criar uso o 
<Codigo - >
var listCreationInfo = new SP.ListCreationInformation();
    listCreationInfo.set_title(nomeLista);
    listCreationInfo.set_templateType(SP.ListTemplateType.pictureLibrary);
<Fim do Codigo - >
para definir que uma biblioteca de imagens que será criada, mas ao fazer o select retorna tudo, não só as bibliotecas que criei

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Você está trabalhando com a biblioteca JCOM do SharePoint. A definição do objeto lista pra essa biblioteca pode ser vista nesse link:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/jj245826(v=office.15).aspx

Repare que há propriedade chamada [`baseTemplate`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/jj246143(v=office.15).aspx).

Quando você cria uma lista, você está indicando o template base dela (pelo seu comentário, `SP.ListTemplateType.pictureLibrary`).

Seu código está quase completo, só falta agora você percorrer todas as listas que obteve na consulta e verificar se o `baseTemplate` delas corresponde ao template de pictureLibrary que você usa para criá-las. Quando corresponder é porque a lista é uma biblioteca de imagens :)

**editando pra incluir código:** basta ajustar seu código mais ou menos assim:

```
/* .. snip .. */
while (listEnumerator.moveNext()) {
    var oList = listEnumerator.get_current();
    if (oList.get_baseTemplate() == SP.ListTemplateType.pictureLibrary) { // Eis o pulo do gato.
        listInfo += oList.get_title() + '\n';
    }
    /* .. snip .. */
}
```

By the way esse `SP.ListTemplateType.pictureLibrary` é um valor constante, 109. Vivendo e aprendendo, eu não conhecia esse template...

Comment: Obrigado Renan, eu não conhecia a propriedade baseTemplate, mas você saberia me dizer como eu aplicaria isto em meu código ? D:
Muito Obrigado !!!

Comment: @PedroElias editei a resposta, dá uma olhada.

Comment: também editei meu código, não consegui aplicar em execução, não retornava nada por conta do select que tive que fazer ... muda algo ?

Comment: Talvez você precise chamar a função `load` do contexto passando a coleção de listas, e aí executar o executeQueryAsync de novo.